# defining a var in loop

Tags: c, for-loop, var

What is difference between defining a var inside a loop or outside? 
for example:

```
int a;
for(int i=1; i<11; i++){
    a = rand()%10;
    printf("%d\n",a);
}
```

the `a` is defined first and then is used in loop. 
but in :

```
for(int i=1; i<11; i++){
    int a = rand()%10;
    printf("%d\n",a);
}
```

here `a` is defined in the loop.
What is difference and which one is slower?

Comment: In the first, you can access `a` after the loop; in the second, you can't.  Otherwise, they're basically the same.  Of course, you could also simply get rid of `a` and use `printf("%d\n", rand() % 10);` — the optimizer might do that for you anyway.

Comment: First build both variants with optimizations enabled. Then take a look at the generated code for both examples to see if there's any difference. And if there is then execute your code a couple of million times to measure. And lastly think about if you really need to bother with such (possible) micro-optimizations (the general answer is ***no***).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude did you just recommend a novice to examine an optimized assembly code to answer a variable scope question?

Comment: Suggestion (**follow canonical usage**): `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Hi, could you please let me know the correct way for initializing the variable in terms of memory usage, I think initializing inside the for-loop would create and free the int-memory in stack again and again which would result in very slightly little more time as compared to initializing the variable outside the loop.

Comment: Optimizers are more intelligent than that.  As you were instructed already, compare the optimized versions of the assembler code for the variants.  They'll be the same, almost certainly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the difference is the scope of the variable. a exists after the loop ends in the 1st case, but does not in the 2nd case.